# MySQL second to formatted date time

Tags: php, mysql

How to convert second to formatted date time in mysql? I have a query to get date difference in second. i.e

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18') sec
```

Now I need to convert this seconds in date time in SQL. Is it possible? Or Is there are any function in mysql to get DATETIME fields difference with formatted option like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('%m %D, %Y %H...', '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18') sec
```

So my expected result is `1 mon 5 day 13 hour 3 sec`

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: Please add some info on how you want the end result to look, as its not clear from your question. PS Edit the question, dont add it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18') secs,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')  mins,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')  hours,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')  days,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')  months,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')  years
```

Giving the result row

```
secs    mins    hours   days    months  years
266783  4446    74      3       0       0
```

You can now do whatever you like with those results

You could now use just the seconds result column to create your output using php like so :-

```
<?php
// of course get this from the result set not a hard coded value
$secs = 266783;
$days = date('d', $secs);

$secs -= $days*24*60*60;
$hours = date('H', $secs);

$secs -= $hours*60*60;
$mins = date('m', $secs);

$secs -= $mins*60;
$seconds = date('s', $secs);

echo sprintf('%d Days %d Hours %d Minutes %d Seconds', $days, $hours, $mins, $seconds );
```

This would output

```
4 Days 2 Hours 12 Minutes 23 Seconds
```

Comment: oh shit. I should have able to do that. But this is not real result. Result should be formatted of `266783` second  as mentioned @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok so now I have done it all for you. I imagine you could do something like that in SQL if you wanted to do everything in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but just tell whether it is possible to get the result with SQL?, what you got by PHP

Comment: This is what i need. Would you please provide that query

Comment: As I dont know how to do it in SQL I will have to hit some books and work out how I would do it. It may be just as quick for you to hit the books and work it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function `date_format(date, format)` [date_format spec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this. here default date specify '2008-01-02'.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2008-01-02', INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2012-06-03 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18') SECOND);
```